# why the method onStart() have a strike symbol in android on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Below is an image of what I get

[image]

Is this an eclipse problem?

When we put any code inside the `onStart()` method it is not working

Comment: It means that function is deprecated.  It still works, but you should use onStartCommand instead of onStart in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `onStart()` has been Deprecated and you can now use `onStartCommand()`

See this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/02/service-api-changes-starting-with.html)

Use `onStartCommand()`.
From google documentation

```
// This is the old onStart method that will be called on the pre-2.0
// platform. 

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    handleStart(intent, startId);
}

//On 2.0 or later we override onStartCommand() so this
// method will not be called.
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleStart(intent, startId);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```